# Relation between lead, Account, oppurtunity and contact

Tags: opportunity, sobject, account, contact, leads

Please explain me the relation between these 4 sobjects. How lead, Account, Opportunity and Contact are related to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into these links must help you
http://www.salesforce.com/customer-resources/learning-center/details/learn-basic-blocks.jsp

http://www.scribd.com/doc/40369664/Understanding-the-Basic-Building-Blocks-of-Salesforce-CRM

Comment: :Nice Information.I am actually keen to know one scenario like if we have a lead that qualifies and becomes an account in SF. Then later on for the same account can we have another lead in SF? and if when this lead qualifies,will it create a new account or would refer the same account which was existing before? .

Comment: It wouldn't create a new account.  The same account will be used.